# SQL -- SELECT 3 TABLES WITH 2 IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to join 3 tables where the two IDs from two tables are related but the third table is not related but the values are. It's very convoluted. I tried running a subquery without luck.

Here's the first table:

```
+---------------------------------+
 | ListID | ListValue | ListLabel |
 +--------------------------------+
 | 1      | 1         | Male      |
 +--------------------------------+
```

Second table:

```
+--------------------+
 | ListID | ListName |
 +-------------------+
 | 1      | Gender   | 
 +-------------------+
```

Third table:

```
+---------------------------------+
 | ClientID | Name      | Gender  |
 +--------------------------------+
 | 23422    | John West | 1       |
 +--------------------------------+
```

So basically I'm looking for the Gender column from the third table to reference the first table where the ListValue column equals the Gender column. Yes, the Gender column value is stored as INT.

```
+---------------------------------+
 | ClientID | Name      | Gender  |
 +--------------------------------+
 | 23422    | John West | Male    |
 +--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Though, in truth, this looks like you have a design flaw, and are storing different properties as a "pointer" to the correct table. If so, what you really need to do if fix your design.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: A join won't work because the third table does not relate to the two tables but the values do.

Comment: *"third table does not relate to the two tables but the values do"* Then if there is no relationship, how can you hope to get the data? Magic...? If there's no relationship you can't achieve what you want reliable because there's no relation of the data.

Comment: I don't think my magic tables suffice. I'm attaching a screenshot.

Comment: Screen shots of data don't help us help you. Provide multiple examples, but if ***you*** don't know how your data relates, then we have no chance; it's your data not ours and only you know how it's defined, not us.

Comment: Again, images of data don't help us help you. Do *not* expect us to transcribe that data; we won't. That's for you to do. *You* can copy that data, put it into a consumable format, we can't copy text out of an image.

Comment: Dynamic sql will be required - and that is likely beyond your abilities. You must "look up" the list for Gender based on the column name and this requires dynamic sql. You suffer from a tortured version of [one desription table](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58372/is-the-one-description-table-to-rule-them-all-approach-good) with a little EAV added

Comment: Yeah, I did not design this. How would I go on this using dynamic SQL? Any insight is welcome

Comment: With the utmost respect, from someone well versed in Dynamic SQL (if I do say so myself), that is not a route you want to go down, @Leonardo . It will be a nightmare to maintain. And that assumes you understand it. If you don't, it'll be impossible and could even be a massive security risk.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu I don't know which route to take. I really thought there was an answer for this.

Comment: There is, fix the design, @Leonardo ; That is the *real* solution. As the answers from [Thorsten Kettner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66646522/2029983) and I both show.

Comment: Alright. I will do that. I will come back with updates! Thanks all!!

Comment: I forgot to mention. Could I just go with CASE statements since I already know the values that correspond to the columns? I know it will be painful to write multiple case statements. Thoughts? @Larnu

Comment: See my answer which demonstrates how to use sub queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very bad data model. Change it if you can.

If there is a column `gender` in the client table, why muddle through with some generic list? Just add a table gender and link to its rows with client.gender_id:

- table gender (gender_id, description)
- table client (client_id, name, gender_id)

If you really must make this generic and are ready to live with the consequences (slower access, no guaranteed consistency, ...), then remove the `gender` column and add a table `client_attribut` instead, consisting of client_id, list_id and list_value.

Anyway, with your current design the query would be

```
select c.clientid, c.name, la.listlabel
from client c
join list_attribute la 
  on la.listvalue = c.gender
  and la.listid = (select listid from list where listname = 'Gender')
order by c.clientid;
```

Comment: Our vendor stores everything in lists! I was able to retrieve the data using a bunch list id's. I agree with everyone that this design has flaws. Nothing that I can do.

Answer (score 3):

From a complete guess, the problem is your design, fix that, fix the problem. You should have 2 tables here, not 3. A Client table and a gender table, and then you can do a trivial `JOIN`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Client (ClientID int NOT NULL,
                         [Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
                         Gender tinyint NULL); --As Gender is Sensitive data, and probably not mandatory as some don't wish to share
ALTER TABLE dbo.Client ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Client PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ClientID);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Gender (GenderID tinyint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                         GenderDescription varchar(15) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE dbo.Gender ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Gender PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (GenderID);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Client ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ClientGender FOREIGN KEY (Gender) REFERENCES dbo.Gender (GenderID);
GO
--Assume existance of data
SELECT C.ClientID,
       C.[Name],
       G.GenderDescription AS Gender
FROM dbo.Client C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Gender G On C.Gender = G.GenderID; --LEFT JOIN as it's NULLable
GO
```

If you must stick with the design you have, you'll probably want to write it as subqueries; and it'll get messy pretty fast:

```sql
SELECT T3.ClientID,
       T3.[Name],
       (SELECT T1.ListLabel
        FROM dbo.Table2 T2
             JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON T2.ListID = T1.ListID
        WHERE T2.ListName = N'Gender'
          AND T1.ListValue = T3.Gender) AS Gender,
       (SELECT T1.ListLabel
        FROM dbo.Table2 T2
             JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON T2.ListID = T1.ListID
        WHERE T2.ListName = N'PrimaryLanguage'
          AND T1.ListValue = T3.PrimaryLanguage) AS PrimaryLanguage
FROM dbo.Table3 T3;
```

You can put these (sub)queries in the `FROM` is you prefer using `APPLY`. I've used an `OUTER` rather than `CROSS APPLY`, as I assume that the value could be `NULL` and thus acts like a `LEFT JOIN`, rather than an `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT T3.ClientID,
       T3.[Name],
       G.Gender,
       PL.PrimaryLanguage
FROM dbo.Table3 T3
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT T1.ListLabel AS Gender
                  FROM dbo.Table2 T2
                       JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON T2.ListID = T1.ListID
                  WHERE T2.ListName = N'Gender'
                    AND T1.ListValue = T3.Gender) G
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT T1.ListLabel AS PrimaryLanguage
                  FROM dbo.Table2 T2
                       JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON T2.ListID = T1.ListID
                  WHERE T2.ListName = N'PrimaryLanguage'
                    AND T1.ListValue = T3.Gender) PL;
```

To make it shorter, you *could* turn the "look up" part of the above into an **inline** table-value function, but I feel that entertaining that is validating the design, and I specifically *don't* want to do that.

This'll be a real pain to keep rewriting, but forced by the design choice. Though you *could* do this with Dynamic SQL, I doubt you'll be able to understand it or maintain it (as if you could understand dynamic SQL you'd have likely at least got the solution I give above), and I doubt you want to write all of your queries as a dynamic statement.

Fix the design, fix the problem (as I mentioned at the start).

Comment: So according to my superiors, I must work on this design. One of them included that I should create a scalar-function, passing the listID & listValue to return the ListLabel. Could you point me in the right direction? :(

Comment: I woukld use an inline TVF, if you must, @Leonardo , but asking that is a different question to what you have here, imo. If you're on SQL Server 2019 you *might * be able to make a performance inline scalar funtion, but if you're on 2017 or prior then a multi-line scalar function is going to tank what little performance you have,.

Comment: Alright, @Larnu I will look into this function. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

A simple join is of course possible, it's just unecessarily convoluted!

```
select t3.ClientId, t3.Name, t1.ListLabel as Gender
from t3 join t2 on t2.ListName='Gender'
join t1 on t1.ListId=t2.ListId and t2.ListValue=t3.Gender
```

Comment: Indeed if the columns being output are derived from data in related tables then that's a hole to climb out of before it's too late :) And yes in that case I agree it would need some d-sql to construct the actual query.